# Getting ERROR on proc 0: Cannot open input script in.crack: No such file or directory(src/lammps.cpp.494)

Tags: cmd, lammps

I am trying to run a simulation on lammps on windows. After I try to run it using the command prompt by writing - "lmp_serial -in in.crack " into the file directory I get the following error.

it shows ERROR on proc 0: Cannot open input script in.crack: No such file or directory(src/lammps.cpp.494)

Please help me fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory: the path to your input script is incorrect. If you want to run it exactly as you've pasted above, your executable and input script be in the same directory.